# Extract table from html file using python

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I want to extract table from an html file. I have written the following code-snippet to extract the first table:

```
import urllib2
import os
import time
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#find('table',{'class':'tbl_with_brdr'})
outfile= open('D:/Dropbox/Python/apelec.txt','wb')
rfile  = open('D:/Dropbox/PRI/Data/AP/195778.html')
rsoup  = BeautifulSoup(rfile)
nodes  = rsoup.find('div',{'class':'frmtext'}).find('table').find('tr')
for node in nodes[1:]:
    x = node.find('th').find('b').get_text().encode("utf-8")
    print x 
    y   = node.find('th').findNext('th').find('b').get_text().encode("utf-8")
    print y
    outfile.write(str(x)+"\t"+str(y)+"\n")
outfile.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
     9 rfile  = open('D:/Dropbox/PRI/Data/AP/195778.html')
     10 rsoup  = BeautifulSoup(rfile)
---> 11 nodes  = rsoup.find('div',{'class':'frmtext'}).find('table').find('tr')
     12 for node in nodes[1:]:
     13     x = node.find('th').find('b').get_text().encode("utf-8")
     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

And the html file is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/panchayat_default.css" type="text/css"/>
<title>consolidated Election Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- To blur the background while processing dwr -->
<div class="faded_div process"></div>
<div  class="popup_block_div process"  style="display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="images/loading_animation.gif" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">                              
</div>

<div id="maincontainer" class="resize">
<div id="headerwrap">   
    <!-- Header -->

<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="/profilerdwr/engine.js"> </script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="/profilerdwr/util.js"> </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/profilerdwr/interface/lgdDao.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common_util_js.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common_css.css" type="text/css"></link>
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
</head>
<body >
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="headerwrap">       
 <div id="header">
 <div id="new_header">
                <div id="logoleft">Area Profiler</div>
        <div id="logoright"></div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="loginnav" align="right">
      <table width="100%" class="tbl_no_brdr">
         <tr>
            <td class="tblclear" align="left">
              <div id="mainnav"><a href="welcome.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU">Home</a> </div>
            </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="topnav">
          <table width="100%" class="tbl_no_brdr">
            <tr>
              <td width="85" class="tblclear">Choose Theme :</td>
              <td width="200" class="tblclear">
                <form id="themeForm" name="themeForm" method="get" action="welcome.do">
                    <input type="hidden" name='OWASP_CSRFTOKEN' value='CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU' />
                    <select name="theme" id="themeId" class="combofield" onchange="submitThemeForm()" style="width: 120px;">
                            <option value="default">Default Theme</option>
                            <option value="mustard">Mustard Theme</option>
                            <option value="peach">Peach Theme</option>
                            <option value="green">Green Theme</option>
                            <option value="blue">Blue Theme</option>
                    </select>

              </form>
              </td>
              <td style="padding: 0px">

            </td>
              <td class="tblclear">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="14" class="tblclear txticon"><a href="#" class="texttoggler " rel="smallview" title="small size"><img src="images/btnMinus.jpg" width="16" height="14" border="0" /></div></a></td>
              <td width="14" class="tblclear txticon"><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="normalview" title="normal size"><img src="images/btnDefault.jpg" width="16" height="14" border="0" /></a> </td>
              <td width="28" class="tblclear txticon"><a href="#" class="texttoggler" rel="largeview" title="large size"><img src="images/btnPlus.jpg" width="16" height="14" border="0" /></a></td>
              <script type="text/javascript" >
                //documenttextsizer.setup("shared_css_class_of_toggler_controls")
                documenttextsizer.setup("texttoggler")            
              </script>
              <td width="100" align="right" class="tblclear">Select Language :</td>
              <td width="108" align="right" class="tblclear">
                <form id="languageForm" name="languageForm" method="get" action="welcome.do">
                <input type="hidden" name='OWASP_CSRFTOKEN' value='CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU' />
                 <select id="languageId" name="language" class="combofield" style="width: 120px;" onchange="submitLanguageForm()" >
                        <option value=""> Select Language </option>

                    </select>
              </form>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div id="breadcrumbnav">  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitThemeForm()
{
    var isOK = confirm("This will Refresh Your Page. Any Unsaved data will be Lost. Do You still want to Continue?");
    if(isOK)
    {
        document.getElementById('themeForm').submit();
    }
    else
    {
        return; 
    }
}

function submitLanguageForm()
{
    var isOK = confirm("This will Refresh Your Page. Any Unsaved data will be Lost. Do You still want to Continue?");
    if(isOK)
    {
        document.getElementById('languageForm').submit();
    }
    else
    {
        return; 
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftpnl">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>

          <td width="100%" valign="top" class="tblclear">
                <!--           content -->.
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common_js.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<script type="text/javascript">
var pathname;
$(document).ready(function() {pathname = window.location.pathname;});
function onBack(s) {
    var position =pathname.indexOf("/", 2);
    var newPath = "";
    var val = s.indexOf("?", 1);
    if(val>0)
        {
        newPath =  s+"&redirect=true";
        }
    else
        {
        newPath =  s+"?redirect=true";
        }
    window.location.replace(".."+pathname.substring(0,position)+"/"+newPath);
}

function downloadReport(repformat){
    //window.location="downloadConsolidatedElectionReportPDF.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU";
     //document.forms["electionReportForm"].action="downloadConsolidatedElectionReportPDF.do?repformat="+repformat+"&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU";
     document.forms["electionReportForm"].action="downloadConsolidatedElectionReportPDF.do?reportformat="+repformat+"&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU";
     document.forms["electionReportForm"].method="POST";
     document.getElementById('electionReportForm').target="_blank";
     document.forms["electionReportForm"].submit();
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.data_link{
    color:blue;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bolder;

}
.disable_link
{
    cursor:default;
    color:blue;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bolder;

}

.data_link:VISITED
{
    color:blue;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.data_link:HOVER{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="frmcontent">
            <div class="frmhd">
                <table width="100%" class="tbl_no_brdr">
                <tr>
                   <td align="left" width="90%">
                       Consolidated Election</td>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
            </div>  
<div class="clear"></div>   
<div class="frmpnlbrdr">                
<div class="frmpnlbg">
<div class="frmtxt">

                <table width="100%" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="tbl_with_brdr">
                        <tr class="tblRowTitle tblclear" >
                            <th align="left" ><b>State Name</b></th>    
                            <th align="left" ><b>Local Body Type</b></th>   
                            <th align="left" ><b>Election Term</b></th> 

                                <th align="left" ><b>Local Body Name</b></th>   

                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tblRowB" style="color: blue;">
                            <th  align="left"  >ANDHRA PRADESH</th> 
                            <th  align="left" >Village Panchayat</th>   
                            <th align="left"  >

                                        02-Aug-2013 &nbsp;&nbsp;To&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                         01-Aug-2018
                            </th>   

                                <th align="left" >KODIHALLI</th>    

                        </tr>
                    </table>

<div class="frmhdtitle">Consolidated Election</div>
<table width="100%" class="tbl_with_brdr">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tblRowTitle tblclear">
                        <th align="center" width="5%" ><b>S.No.</b></th>
                        <th align="left"   width="9%"><b>Name</b></th>        0
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Age</b></th>           1
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Caste Category</b></th>  2
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Gender</b></th>         3
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Qualification</b></th>  4
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Occupation</b></th>     5
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Email Address</b></th>   6
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Ward Name</b></th>       7
                        <th align="left" width="9%"><b>Reservation</b></th>    8
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >1</td>
                <td>Kambanna</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Middle or Lower Secondary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td >

                     Yes  (OBC / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                <tr class="tblRowA">

                <td  align="center" >2</td>
                <td>Ramesh</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Middle or Lower Secondary</td>
                <td>Workers not reporting any occupations</td>
                <td>

                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 1</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (OBC / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >3</td>
                <td>S.Manjunath</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Higher Secondary or Intermediate or Pre University or Senior Secondary</td>
                <td>Workers not reporting any occupations</td>
                <td>

                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 2</td>
                <td >

                                No (General / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                <tr class="tblRowA">

                <td  align="center" >4</td>
                <td>Obuleshu</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Below Primary</td>
                <td>Workers not reporting any occupations</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 3</td>
                <td >

                                No (General / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >5</td>
                <td>Mamatha</td>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Matriculation or Junior School Certificate or Secondary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>

                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 4</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (General / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                <tr class="tblRowA">

                <td  align="center" >6</td>
                <td>Shivamma</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Below Primary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 5</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (General / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >7</td>
                <td>Hanumantappa</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>SC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Illiterate</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 6</td>
                <td >

                                No (General / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

                <tr class="tblRowA">

                <td  align="center" >8</td>
                <td>Malingappa</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>SC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Illiterate</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 7</td>
                <td >

                                No (General / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>
                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >9</td>
                <td>Kamalamma</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Illiterate</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 8</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (OBC / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>


                <tr class="tblRowA">


                <td  align="center" >10</td>
                <td>Muddamma</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Illiterate</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 9</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (General / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>


                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >11</td>
                <td>Patta Tayamma</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>SC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Middle or Lower Secondary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 10</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (SC / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>


                <tr class="tblRowA">


                <td  align="center" >12</td>
                <td>Sujatha</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>OBC</td>
                <td>Female</td>
                <td>Middle or Lower Secondary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 11</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (OBC / Female)

                </td>           
            </tr>



                            <tr class="tblRowB"> 

                <td  align="center" >13</td>
                <td>Kadurappa</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>SC</td>
                <td>Male</td>
                <td>Middle or Lower Secondary</td>
                <td>N/A</td>
                <td>


                            N/A

                </td>
                <td>Ward no 12</td>
                <td >

                                Yes (SC / Others)

                </td>           
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<table width="100%" class="tbl_no_brdr">
      <tr>
          <td align="center">
               <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="onClose('welcome.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU')"     value=Close />


                    <input  type="button" class="btn" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait .!';onBack('consolidatedElectionReport.do?OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=CN72-BGJW-G7FM-K1S3-P5FF-V1EN-IO4T-GHWU&electionTermId=35107&stateId=28')" value=Back />

          </td>
      </tr>
</table>  

<form id="electionReportForm" name="electionReportForm" action="#" method="post">
<div align="center"><br/>
    <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="downloadReport('pdf');" value="Export to PDF" size="5" />
    <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="downloadReport('xls');" value="Export to Excel" size="5" />
</div>
</form>               

</div>
        <div class="myclass"
            style="font-family: Times; text-align: center; font-size: 10.0pt; color: white; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid gray">
            Report generated through Area Profiler (http://areaprofiler.gov.in)Thu Oct 02 22:34:20 IST 2014

        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer"> 
<!--    Footer -->


<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<table width="100%"  class="tbl_no_brdr">
         <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="fotbrdr"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td width="161" class="btmlogospace"><a href="http://www.negp.gov.in/" target= "_blank" ><img src="images/e_governance_logo.jpg" width="161" height="38" /></a></td>
          <td width="93" class="btmlogospace"><a href="http://www.panchayat.gov.in/" target= "_blank" ><img src="images/panchayatilogo.jpg" width="93" height="38" /></a></td>

          <td align="right" class="btmlogospace">Site is designed, hosted
                and maintained by National Informatics Centre<br /> Contents on
                this website is owned,updated and managed by the Ministry of
                Panchayati Raj</td>
        </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>


</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show the full traceback with the html content if possible.

Comment: In which line is this happening? Please edit the full error message in.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question with the full error message and also provided a link to the html file. I need to extract the table from the file. As you can see the file name is numeric, I need to iterate the code over many such files with names in the range 195100-195800. Kindly help

Comment: Your HTML file contains *multiple documents*. That means the parser has to make the best of what is essentially a malformed document. One of your `.find()` call fails (no element is found) and then the rest just falls apart. Reduce your file to just *one* document and find what element is missing. Fix that, etc.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Thanks for replying. How did you make out if the file contains multiple documents.  If you open the link you see just a single doc so I am confused I am rather new to html/ python, so would like to understand.https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f82tivkn2jmufi/195778.html?dl=0

Comment: I opened the file you uploaded to dropbox and it doesn't contain any element of class 'frmtext', the one you are looking for, it contains 'frmtxt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I paste here an approach, it is not exactly the solution but you can use it as a guide.
You have to traverse the DOM tree and extract the values you want.
I changed the class of the div you look for from frmtext to frmtxt and in the traversal you have to check if anything is found or not.

```
import urllib2
import os
import time
import traceback
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


outfile= open('out.txt','wb')
rfile  = open('195778.html')
rsoup  = BeautifulSoup(rfile)
nodes1  = rsoup.find('div',{'class':'frmtxt'})
nodes = nodes1.find('table').find_all('tr')
for node in nodes:
a = node.find('th') 
x = None   
if a != None:
    x1 = x.find('b')
    if x1 != None:
        x2 = x1.get_text().encode("utf-8")        
        print x2 
        x = x2
y = node.find('th')
if y != None: 
    print 'y',y
    y2  = y.findNext('th')
    if y2 != None:
        print 'y2',y2
        y3 = y2.find('b')
        if y3 != None:
            y = y3.get_text().encode("utf-8")               
            print y
outfile.write(str(x)+"\t"+str(y)+"\n")
outfile.close()
```